# check box enable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr id="tr99"><td>......</td></tr>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggletr(this);" value="val" id="cbox" />
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

function toggletr(obj)
{
    if(obj.checked) 
        $(#tr99).hide();
    else  
        $(#tr99).show();
}
```

hi.this is my code that runs in add page  of  staff.
 if user  is  in edit mode the value   that  value is  checked in the  code
i mean to say in .cs .
 `checkbox.checked ="true"` means . that  time  i need  to make that  tr value  "tr99" is  visiable  true
  if  checkbox  is  not  checked then  make the  tr  as  hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want this to happen

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    function toggletr(obj){
        if(obj.checked){
            $("#tr99").show();
            $("#cbox").attr("value", "tr99");
        }else {
            $("#tr99").hide();
        }
    }

});
```

Is that it? You can also add the function directly

```
function toggletr(obj){
    if(obj.checked){
        $("#tr99").show();
        $("#cbox").attr("value", "tr99");
    }else {
        $("#tr99").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the `toggletr` method out of the "`$(document).ready(function() {`"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggletr(obj){
        if(obj.checked)
            $('#tr99').hide();
        else
            $('#tr99').show();}
</script>
<tr id="tr99"><td>......</td></tr>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggletr(this);" value="val" id="cbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd set the onclick method to be an event handler:

```
$(function(){ 
$('#cbox').click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $("#tr99").show();
        $("#cbox").attr("value", "tr99");
    }else {
        $("#tr99").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to do pure jQuery and not mix in normal Javascript (obj.checked)....

```
$(function(){
    $("#cbox").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#tr99").show();
        }else{
            $("#tr99").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `if (this.checked) {...}` is simpler, more efficient and more readable.

Comment: I agree, it is simpler, more efficient and readable. I was just trying to offer alternatives. Getting familiar with jQuery's is function helps for checking other things like visibility. If you're to be doing other checks using "is" in your code, then I would argue consistency is better than simplicity. Additionally, wrapping the check in jQuery then allows for method chaining.

But again, I agree in this single case that "this.checked" is better.